# converting existing website to multilingual website of asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to convert my existing website which is created in asp.net mvc  to a multilingual without resource file.I have a lot of client side content (obtained through ajax in javascript) what is the best possible way?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why no resource files?  They're so good and work with sitemaps, data annotation attributes, error messages, and everything else.  I would consider it a real loss to approach this topic without bringing in resource files.  Also, they're very easy to update, omit certain languages or phrases, organize (e.g. sitemapresource, exceptionresource, expressionresource, layoutresource).

Comment: What about the content which is written on the cshtml page directly (without using labelfor())for the various popups in the application

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't stray too far from resource files. They're meant to be used for localization, and they're good at it. You may need to template some JSON strings from a resource file, but that'll be faster than a DB lookup, or file read.

For the purpose of localizing client-side content to be displayed to the user, are partial views possible? You'll get the benefit of the typical MVC pipeline (i.e. passing through the localization modules) but also get the content via an Ajax query.

Comment: I want to ask how to convert various alert and normal message(without using model validation) which has to displayed on popups.